# C, No output of my switch statement on console

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement

I am currently trying to practice the functions I've learned in university for an upcoming test. I am trying to use these following functions; `if`, `switch`, `scanf`, `printf`, `for`.

However, when I try to execute my program on the console, once I put an input in the variable `n`, the switch function shows no output on the console and the program ends.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(void) {
    int n,i,x,y,z;
    float res;
    printf("Please input x,y,z using (,)\n");
    scanf("%d,%d,%d",&x,&y,&z);
    printf("You inputed the following numbers: x=%d, y=%d, z=%d\n",x,y,z);
    printf("Which of the following equations would you like to run?\n");
    printf("x+y/z ?? (1)\n");
    printf("sqrt(z)+(x^3/y) ?? (2)\n");
    printf("The average number of the three entered ?? (3)\n");
    printf("Print the word 'test' as many times as is the sum of x,y,z ?? (4)\n");
    scanf(" %d",n);
    switch(n)
    {
    case 1:
        if(z!=0)
        {
            res=(float)(x+y)/z;
            printf("The result is: %f \n",res);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Division by zero?!\n");
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if((z>=0)&&(y!=0))
        {
            res=(float)sqrt(z)+((float)pow(x,3)/y);
            printf("The result is: %f \n",res);
        }
        else if(z<0)
        {
            printf("Square root attempted to use negative integer\n");
        }
        else if(y=0)
        {
            printf("You cannot devide with zero\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("what?");
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        res=x+y+z/(float)3;
        printf("The average of x+y+z is: %f\n",res);
        break;
    case 4:
        res=x+y+z;
        for(i=1; i<res; ++i)
        {
            printf("test\n");
        }
        break;
    default:
        printf("Please input a number between 1-4!!!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf(" %d",&n);`

Comment: Be aware that if/switch/while/for are *not* functions, but (control flow) statements (but scanf/printf are).

Comment: *once I put an input in the variable "n"* So maybe set a breakpoint and see what's going on with `n`? It might not be what you expect. Also, check the console for messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be in this statement
`scanf(" %d",n);`
Change it to
`scanf(" %d",&n);`
**Explanation:** `scanf(" %d",n);` doesn't allow the user to type in on the console because of the missing address operator `&`

Answer (score 0):

modify `scanf(" %d",n);` to `scanf(" %d",&n);` just like you did on the first scanf line for x,y,z. 
You also need to `#include <math.h>` if you want to use `sqrt()` and `pow()` 
It is also good practice to initialize all the variables